# ValueError: Name undefined in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting "Name undefined warning while compiling with try-catch block". Please give some idea about this error.

[NAME UNDEFINED ERROR IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khvSe.jpg)

```
# Importing random package
import random
try:
    top_range = int(input("Enter the range:"))
except ValueError:
    print("Please enter he Integer Number")
# Getting the random number from system
sys_guess = random.randint(0, top_range)
print("System Guess =", sys_guess)
print("Try to GUESS the Number within 3 entries, MAXIMUM 3 guess......!")
# making for increment
guess = 0
# Guessing the number
while sys_guess >= 0:
    user_input = int(input("Enter guessed number: "))
    if sys_guess != user_input:
        # incrementing the wrong value
        guess += 1
        print("Wrong Guess-->")
        if guess == 2:
            print("you have only one guess left")
        if guess > 2:
            print("Maximum number of guess tried, Failed to obtain the guess!!!!!")
            break
    else:
        # incrementing the correct value
        guess += 1
        print("!HURRAY***CORRECT GUESS***!")
        if sys_guess == user_input:
            break
# printing the total number of guess
print("Total Guesses=", guess)
```

Comment: You never set `top_range` if there's an exception. And post all errors here directly as text with the stack trace.

Comment: You don't provide the user an opportunity to enter *another* number if the exception is raised.

Comment: how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick the try catch block in a loop that will continue endlessly until the user enters a valid number. If there is an exception at the moment the top_range value is never defined thus the error.

```
while True:
    try:
        top_range = int(input("Enter the range:"))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter he Integer Number")
```